# Unable to download google app engine standard project source in Windows 10

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to download the latest version of one of my existing google appengine projects & I am tired of seeing the errors! I am running the appcfg.py command inside the google sdk python 2.7 dir. Here's what I ran.

```
python "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\appcfg.py" download_app -A <project> -V <version> C:\DEV_Tools\Dump\
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 66, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import appinfo
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 54, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import validation
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\validation.py", line 46, in <module>
    from google.appengine._internal.ruamel import yaml
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\ruamel\yaml\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from google.appengine._internal.ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from google.appengine._internal.ruamel.yaml.loader import BaseLoader, SafeLoader, Loader, RoundTripLoader  # NOQA
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\ruamel\yaml\loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.appengine._internal.ruamel.yaml.constructor import (
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.appengine._internal.ruamel.yaml.comments import *                               # NOQA
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\ruamel\yaml\comments.py", line 642, in <module>
    class CommentedMap(MutableMapping, ordereddict, CommentedBase):
  File "C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Python27\lib\abc.py", line 86, in __new__
    cls = super(ABCMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases CommentedBase, MutableMapping, ordereddict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be an issue with the installed files on your system. I have tried to reproduced the issue however I got different kind of error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in 
>   run_file(**file**, globals())   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
>   execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_) NameError: name
>   'execfile' is not defined

This was due to corrupted installation files. I have completely reinstalled Google App Engine Python SDK and it worked for me. Try the steps below as it might help you as well:

**Downloading Source code from GAE:**

- It only works for App Engine Standard apps
- You can confirm that as in you Google Cloud Console where you choose the version of a specific service. The dropdown menu `Tools` will not give option **Source** for Flex apps but only for **Standard** apps
- You should have `Python version 2.7` installed
- You should have latest version of `App Engine SDK for Python`

**Steps:**

1. Go to the **Control Panel > Programs & Features** and uninstall your **Google App Engine** SDK.
2. Go to the path where GAE was installed and delete the **google_appengine** folder. In your occasion it is `C:\DEV_Tools\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform`
3. Install `Python 2.7` [from here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)
4. Install and initialize Google Cloud SDK from [Quickstart for Windows](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows)
5. Run Google Cloud SDK as administrator and execute `$ gcloud init`
6. Then execute `$ gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]` based on [gcloud config set doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#project).
7. Execute `$ gcloud components install app-engine-python` to install GAE Python based on [Download the Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download#installing-cloud-sdk-for-python)
8. Execute `$ gcloud components install app-engine-python-extras` to install extras.
9. Execute `$ gcloud components update` to update the components.
10. Install GAE SDK for Python as it is mentioned in [Download and install the original App Engine SDK for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download#python_windows)
11. Restart your computer
12. Run Google Cloud SDK as `Administrator`
13. Execute the command `$ gcloud info` to verify that the correct project and correct user account is setup.
14. If it is not setup properly the execute `$ gcloud init` and set up properly to authenticate the SDK.
15. Execute `appcfg.py -A [PROJECT_ID] -V [VERSION_NAME] download_app C:\PATH\TO\SAVE\SOURCE_CODE` **Make sure that the version is referring to an GAE STANDARD app**
16. It will redirect you to an browser page so you could login with the same account that you set up the SDK for authentication.

You should see:

```
Authentication successful.
04:37 PM Fetching files...
04:37 PM [1/16] WEB-INF/lib/_ah_compiled_jsps-0000.jar
04:37 PM [2/16] WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
04:37 PM [3/16] WEB-INF/min-quickstart-web.xml
04:37 PM [4/16] WEB-INF/appengine-generated/app.yaml
04:37 PM [5/16] WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.jdt.ecj-3.14.0.jar
04:37 PM [6/16] WEB-INF/web.xml
04:37 PM [7/16] WEB-INF/lib/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.5.24.2.jar
04:37 PM [8/16] WEB-INF/lib/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.5.24.2.jar
04:37 PM [9/16] source-context.json
04:37 PM [10/16] WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml
04:38 PM [11/16] WEB-INF/classes/source-context.json
04:38 PM [12/16] WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
04:38 PM [13/16] WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
04:38 PM [14/16] WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.4.14.v20181114-nolog
```

Otherwise if it is GAE Flex you will see this error:

```
54319 download_app C:\PATH\TO\SAVE\SOURCE_CODE 04:38 PM Host:
appengine.google.com 04:38 PM Fetching file list... Error 400: ---
begin server output --- Major version "[VERSION_NAME]" does not exist.
--- end server output ---
```

Comment: I usually rely on ubuntu for such stuff. but I had to use windows at that time. Thank you for the tip. I forgot to mark it. Sorry for the delay.